# Migrating from Evernote to Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, evernote

For numerous reasons, I've decided to ditch Evernote, and find Google Docs to be the best replacement.

Now I want to migrate all my (thousands of) notes. Exporting HTML from Evernote and then importing to Google Docs works great. All formatting is preserved, and it's easy to do many at once.

I can even tweak the HTML before uploading to Drive (like changing fonts, colors, etc.)

The only issue I have is with **images**. Evernote exports all images as `img` links to separate folders with the name `NoteName.resources` which Google Docs does not include in the converted file.

Is there any tool/method/plugin/script that will convert HTML to Google Doc and also handle images?

Evernote can also export XML files with the `.enex` extension which contain both the HTML and all the images embedded (and base64 encoded) ... but I don't know if there's a way to convert those to Google Docs.

Or maybe there's a way to convert all the `img` tags in the HTML files to embedded base64?

NOTE: I know there are many online services which claim to be able to do this in the cloud (IFTTT, Zapier, MultCloud, CloudHQ, etc.) but a lot of this data is sensitive and I do not trust any of them.

Comment: Does Evernote allow to export to .docx format?

Comment: @Rubén No, just HTML and XML. I'm considering trying Evernote>HTML>Word>Google...

Comment: Maybe not related to your question.. would you mind sharing your reasons for Evernote? I use microsoft word online/offline for notes. But I hear people rave about evernote all the time. I have been thinking of trying it out...

Answer (score 2):

I just found a two-step workaround for this.  This will only work for Mac users, but maybe a similar approach can work on Windows?

I exported the `.enex` file from Evernote, and then imported that into Bear, an Evernote competitor that only runs on macOS/iOS.  Great product, but we decided to consolidate everything into Google Drive.

From Bear, I was able to export all notes to `.docx` format, which preserved the images, and simply upload them into Google Drive.